# how to Convert Chinese Number to English in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here, This is the Code of Converting English Number into Chinese but I get nil in the number

```
- (void)convertChineseToEnglish {
    NSString *NumberString = @"九十九";
    NSNumberFormatter *Formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"];
    [Formatter setLocale:locale];
    NSNumber *newNum = [Formatter numberFromString:NumberString];
    if (newNum) {
        NSLog(@"%@", newNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `NSLocalizedString`

Comment: But I want to Convert Directly JSON Response into Chinese Text So How Can I do that

Comment: need to convert whole JSON Response into Chinese Language ?

Comment: Any Other Way To Convert JSON Response into Chinese

Comment: If you radically change your question, do not edit, ask a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shebuka notes, these are considered spelled out numbers by iOS, so you need to use the "spelled out" number style to parse them.

```
NSString *chinese = @"九十九";
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];

// You will be parsing Chinese characters
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"zh"];

// You will be parsing spelled-out numbers
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle;

// And now parse the number
NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:chinese];

// Now it's a number. You can output it in English by changing the formatter
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"];

// Prints "ninety-nine"
NSLog(@"Spelled-out English: %@", [formatter stringFromNumber:number]);

// Or get it in Arabic numerals.
// You can do this without changing the locale, since Chinese also uses Arabic numerals.
// Prints "99"
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
NSLog(@"In arabic numerals: %@", [formatter stringFromNumber:number]);
```

NSNumberFormatter also understands the "bank" version of these digits. For example, it will also parse "玖拾玖" as 99.

Answer (score 0):

I dont get the actual question but i guess you need this

**Change language inside the app:**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: your_lang, nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code spells numbers

- *99* spells like "*ninety-nine*"

with a given Chinese locale

- *ninety-nine* in `zh_Hans_CN` locale is 九十九 (*Jiǔ shí jiǔ*)

so it's not converting English text into Chinese text at all...

To "convert" generic text you need to use some translation service/api.

Comment: But I don't know which Service API i can use